# NodeJs: Initalize class and inject into services

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, dependency-injection

I'm just starting to build a NodeJs server with express. I write the server in typescript for a better overview.

My problem or question is the following:

I need a certain class in different services. This class needs a lot of time for initialization, because some data is parsed and some algorithms are run through. Is it possible to initialize this class when starting the server and to copy the class or a copy of the class into the individual services without reference or dependencies to objects? Especially when calling the controller in parallel, these dependencies must not exist.

Thank you very much!

Comment: What have you tried so far? There a many references out on the googles that could help you. For example https://isamatov.com/node-js-dependency-injection-container/

Comment: A short snippet to show you what I'm going for. Please note that the validator is not stateless and stores some data in variable/properties of the class when executing the function. Can I call the class so injection despite parallel?

``` lang-js
import express from 'express';
import Validator from 'custom-package';

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

let validator = new Validator();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  let result = validator.DoSomeStuff(req);
  res.send(result);
});

app.listen(...);
```